# Laravel 7 - How do I rebind repository on Validator::extend() for tests?

Tags: php, laravel, ddd-repositories

I have set up a custom validation rule like this:

// Custom created RepositoryProvider.php also registered in app.php 'providers' array.

```
public $bindings = [
    UserRepository::class => EloquentUserRepository::class,
];

public function boot(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    Validator::extend('user_email_unique', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) use($userRepository) {
        return !$userRepository->findByEmailAddress($value)->exists();
    });
}
```

// my test

```
class SignUpUserActionTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app->bind(UserRepository::class, function() {
            return new UserRepositoryMock();
        });
    }
}
```

In my test I rebind the UserRepository to a mock. It works fine in for the fetching of data, but it maintains the original binding for the validation extension and does not rebind the repository used. They therefore use two different implementations when unit tests are run.

How can I extend the validator so that the automatic resolution is rebound on tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do you logic in your `RepositoryProvider`, this will be instantiated in your `parent::setUp()` call and thereby fetch your `UserRepository` before the binding has been mocked. Move the binding before this call and i will assume you will get a different result.

```
public function setUp() : void
{
    $this->app->bind(UserRepository::class, function() {
        return new UserRepositoryMock();
    });

    parent::setUp();
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, the cause was right the solution was not. Resolve `UserRepository` in the closure, will most likely make it resolve at a time where your binding is set.

```
Validator::extend('user_email_unique', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    $userRepository = resolve(UserRepository::class);
    return !$userRepository->findByEmailAddress($value)->exists();
});
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not the solution. There is no `$this->app` before the parent::setUp method is called - resulting in "Call to a member function bind() on null".

Comment: The edited answer (re)solves the problem ;-) Thanks.
Strangely enough since the boot method should resolve dependencies from the container.

Comment: Resolve dependencies from the container? the closure is first run when it uses the validator, so then your mock will be resolved.